# SSRS and Dynamic pivot: Grouping

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, grouping

I cannot seem to create a grouping after dynamically pivoting a result set. There is already a grouping by rownumber, but I need to be able to create an addition group(after the grouping by row number)
[Result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fqyv.png)

I need to be able to create a salesrepcode grouping. However, because this dynamic, the fieldname is not accessible prior. Is there a way to use a parameter to do this grouping?

EDIT:

Background:
I have sales data that have aggregates by dates(rolling 12th period). I pivot the data so that I have the dynamic dates as headers. It goes into this matrix
[Matrix raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQcbv.png)
and grouped by Rownumber
[Grouping by Rownumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or8Vw.png)

Record set view
[Record set result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pijCF.png)

Problem:

I need this data to be in a tabbed format when exporting to Excel by repcode
The only way I know is to have a grouping on the salesrepcode to produce the result below.
[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8zs8.png)

I am not able to add a grouping that produces the desired outcome.
I am open to any ideas. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show what it is that you are wanting to achive?  It isn't clear if you are wanting to pivot by the salesrepcode or trying to summarise the result further.!

Comment: As harry said, you need to show more info. Show a screen shot of you report design and the row group setting as well as what you expect the final output to look like.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated